# How to simulate "empirical" fixed effects in linear mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation

Is there a way to simulate a linear mixed model where the estimated fixed effects match the fixed effects one specifies in the simulation?

At first I assumed that the following code would achieve this.
Please note: I set `empirical = TRUE` within the `MASS:mvrnom` function.

```
library("lme4")
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame("subject" = gl(10, 6),
                "condition" = gl(2, 1, 60, labels = c("A", "B")),
                "X" = rep(0:1, 30),
                "b1" = 50)
d$subject_intercept <- MASS::mvrnorm(nlevels(d$subject), 
                                     mu = 0, 
                                     Sigma = 5^2,
                                     empirical = TRUE) [d$subject]
d$noise <- MASS::mvrnorm(nrow(d), 
                         mu = 0, 
                         Sigma = 3^2, 
                         empirical = TRUE)

d <- within(d, y <- b1 * X + subject_intercept + noise)

print(m1 <- lmer(y ~ condition + (1|subject), d))
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ condition + (1 | subject)
   Data: d
REML criterion at convergence: 323.7271
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 4.412   
 Residual             3.035   
Number of obs: 60, groups:  subject, 10
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)   conditionB  
    -0.2248      50.4496
```

However, the fixed effect estimates for the intercept and the contrast ("conditionB") are:

- *intercept*: the simulated (constant) effect of condition A + the mean of the simulated residuals within this condition
- *contrast*: the simulated (constant) effect of condition B + the mean of the simulated residuals within this condition - the *intercept* (because of `contrast.treatment`)

```
effect_A <- with(subset(d, condition == "A"), mean(b1 * X + noise))
all.equal(fixef(m1)[[1]], effect_A)
[1] TRUE
effect_B <- with(subset(d, condition == "B"), mean(b1 * X + noise))
all.equal(fixef(m1)[[2]], effect_B - effect_A)
[1] TRUE
```

This seems to be a problem because AFAIK one usually only specifies the residual variation and the mean of the residuals (0) across conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the mean of the simulated residuals is not *exactly* zero, the model cannot possibly disentangle the mean residual from the true effect. Nevertheless, the model clearly does a good job in taking sampling variability into account, because both your estimates are less than one standard error from their true values.
And if you increase the number of observations you can get as close as you want to the original values used in the simulation.

*Edit*: In your code the mean of the residual is zero but only when summed over the whole dataset, i.e. pooling together the two conditions A and B. The residuals' means are not zero when averaged separately in the two conditions, hence the difference between the estimates and the true generative values. I don't think it is possible to obtain the same exact values of the fixed-effects used in the simulation, unless you force the residuals to sum to zero within conditions, e.g. code below.

```
library("lme4")
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame("subject" = gl(10, 6),
                "condition" = gl(2, 1, 60, labels = c("A", "B")),
                "X" = rep(0:1, 30),
                "b1" = 50)
d$subject_intercept <- MASS::mvrnorm(nlevels(d$subject), 
                                     mu = 0, 
                                     Sigma = 5^2,
                                     empirical = TRUE) [d$subject]

# simulate residuals separately to make sure they sum to zero within conditions
d$noise[d$condition=="A"] <- MASS::mvrnorm(nrow(d[d$condition=="A",]), 
                         mu = 0, 
                         Sigma = 3^2*(60-1)/(60-2), 
                         empirical = TRUE)

d$noise[d$condition=="B"] <- MASS::mvrnorm(nrow(d[d$condition=="B",]), 
                         mu = 0, 
                         Sigma = 3^2*(60-1)/(60-2), 
                         empirical = TRUE)

d <- within(d, y <- b1 * X + subject_intercept + noise)

# now the fixed-effect estimates are the same as the true values, up to some numerical error
print(m1 <- lmer(y ~ condition + (1|subject), d))

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ condition + (1 | subject)
   Data: d
REML criterion at convergence: 327.9733
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 4.635   
 Residual             3.141   
Number of obs: 60, groups:  subject, 10
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)   conditionB  
  -3.44e-14     5.00e+01
```

*Edit 2*: When setting `empirical=TRUE` the values generated are such that the sample variance computed using Bessel correction (that is by using of $n-1$ instead of $n$ in the denominator) correspond exactly to the one used for generating the values. In the code above the residuals are generated for two smaller vectors of length 30 instead of a single one of length 60, hence the estimated sample variance would be different from the intended value, unless this value is corrected as pointed out by @amoeba in his comment. In this particular case one needs to multiply the desired value by $\frac{60-1}{60-2}$, and more generally if one wants to generate a sample of length $n$ by concatenating $k$ vectors of equal length, the standard deviation used to generate each of the $k$ vectors should be multiplied by the factor $\frac{n-1}{n-k}$.

Comment: Doesn't `empirical = TRUE` guarantee that the mean of simulated residuals *is* exactly zero?

Comment: @amoeba: Yes, it does. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: it is zero if you sum over the whole simulated dataset, `mean(d$noise)` $\approx 0$. Why would you expect them to sum to zero for any particular subset?

Comment: I state in my Q that this not true for subsets (e.g. condition A and B). The Q asks whether one can simulate the specified effects if only the effects, the  intercept variance and the residual variance are given. If the answer is that one cannot do this then that's fine.

Comment: Re your edit: doesn't this change the overall residual variance?

Comment: @statmerkur If sample A has mean 0 and variance sigma^2, and sample B has mean 0 and variance sigma^2, then shouldn't the combined sample {A,B} have mean 0 and variance sigma^2?

Comment: @amoeba: No, compare `var(d$noise)` (9) in my code with `var(d$noise)` (8.847458) in @Matteo Lisi's code

Comment: @statmerkur Yeah, that's because of the Bessel's correction: (9*(30-1) + 9*(30-1))/(2*30-1) = 8.847458. This means that if you want to get 9 as `var(d$noise)` then you should supply 9*(60-1)/(60-2) = 9.155172 as the variance for A and B.

Comment: @statmerkur I edited the answer to make this change. I think this answers the question "Is there a way to simulate a linear mixed model where the estimated fixed effects match the fixed effects one specifies in the simulation?"

Comment: @amoeba: Yeah, Bessel's correction does the trick.

Comment: ... and I think it would improve the A if Bessel's correction would be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Maybe this procedure is helpful for simulating mixed models in general (without `empirical = TRUE` and drawing many samples). Probably it doesn't make a difference in the long run as the residuals will even out regardless of whether one forces the residuals to sum to zero within conditions or not, though. What do you think?